# azureml inference config how to call yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

how do I pass a yaml file to inference config? the yaml file is in the same source directory as my score.py file

my yaml script is called score_env.yaml

```
name: inference_environment
dependencies:
- python=3.8.1

- pip:
- azureml-defaults
- numpy
- scikit-learn
- joblib
- pandas
```

is the following correct

```
inf_conf = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py",environment="score_env.yaml",source_directory=folder_path)
```

or would i do this instead

```
inf_conf = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py",environment="inference_environment",source_directory=folder_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that you can use either `conda_file` and pass in a file name or `environment` and pass in an [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment(class)?view=azure-ml-py) object.

So, in your case, you would want to use `conda_file`:

```py
inf_conf = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py", conda_file="score_env.yaml", source_directory=folder_path)
```

[link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the answer here[1], I was able to get this working by initiating a new environment:

```
from azureml.core.environment import Environment

myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name="myenv", file_path="score_env.yaml")
```

and then pass this to the inference_config:

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(source_directory=folder_path,
                                        entry_script="score.py",
                                        environment=myenv)
```

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437607/how-to-create-azure-ml-inference-config-and-deployment-config-class-objects-from#:~:text=CONDA_ENV_FILE_PATH%2C%20%27myenv.yml%27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437607/how-to-create-azure-ml-inference-config-and-deployment-config-class-objects-from#:%7E:text=CONDA_ENV_FILE_PATH%2C%20%27myenv.yml%27))-,myenv%20%3D%20Environment.from_conda_specification(name%3D%22myenv%22%2C%20file_path%3D%22myenv.yml%22),-script_file_name%20%3D%20%27inference/score